# Who manufactured US 10th Cavalry Saber?

Tags: identification, cavalry, sword, army

[image]My grandfather - Henry Abbey Jr. was a Lt. in the US Army 10th Cavalry out of Fort Huachuca in AZ. I have photos of him - and there is one in the Fort Museum - and I have his saber/sword. I'm wondering if there is a known manufacturer of these sabers.

[image]
The blade is etched and has his name etched as well. I can scan an upload a photo of him in that uniform as well. In the bottom picture is this article Lt Abbey is the shorter
officer on the far right.

Comment: Please post images and detailed measurements *of the sword* you wish identified..

Comment: Backing up justCal. The rest of the pictures and text here round out an interesting story, but this looks at its core to be an identification question, and for metal work those are best answered with good high-resolution pictures of the object in question, and particularly any identifying marks.

Comment: A better date would also be very useful. When did he serve?  I'd be somewhat surprised if 10th cav had an independent procurement. I suspect all cav sabers are sourced from one supplier.  I can find the supplier for the prior model with a google search.  Where have you looked?>

Comment: An officer's saber or sword would most likely be a private purchase rather than an item of issue.  Officers provided their own uniforms and accoutrements.  It would be of the issue pattern, but produced by a high end manufacturer.  You should look on the blade where it enters the guard for manufacturer's marks.  Uniforms and accoutrements were usually advertised in the Journal of the United States Cavalry Association or the Army & Navy Journal.  Mostly purveyors of uniforms, the firms in the trade would contract with a manufacturer to build individual swords on order complete with engraving.

Comment: Very short article on the 1913 "Patton" saber can be found here  on page 24.  Shows the Springfield Armory makers mark on page 25. See https://history.army.mil/armyhistory/AH90(W).pdf

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer

> Over 35,000 were manufactured at the Springfield Armory, Springfield, MA, between 1913 and 1918.
> . . . .

> An additional 93,000 sabers were contracted to the firm of Landers, Frary and Clark for production in 1917 and 1918. They have the L F & C marking in place of SA, usually have no serial number, but may bear an inspector number. All are dated 1918 and 1919. [*springfieldedge*](https://www.springfieldedge.com/saber_m-1913.html)

[Militaryhistoryonline](https://www.militaryhistoryonline.com/WWI/CavalrySaber) quotes the same source.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone.  With my husband's help and a much better magnifying glass - we determined the sword bears the insignia of WMH - Horstmann Co, Philadelphia. Horstman was from Germany and the Horstman logo also features a Star of David. The silver plating is in need of repair, and it was difficult to read the information. Not sure if I will try to have it re-plated? Here's what I found on Horstmann:

William H. Horstmann & Co. (later Horstmann Brothers and Company) was a manufacturer and retailer of civilian and military equipment, including military uniforms, insignias, and flags. The company was established in 1815 by William H. Horstmann (1785-1850), a native of Cassel, Germany. He learned the trade of silk-weaving in France, and upon emigrating to the United States, established himself in Philadelphia as a manufacturer of fringe, laces, and trimmings of various kinds.

In 1828, the company began the manufacture of military trimmings. The company consisted of two branches: one dealt in civilian clothing and goods, and the other in military uniforms and equipment. The company executive large government contracts for the War and Navy Departments.

After his sons, William H. Horstmann (1819-1872) and Sigmund H. Horstmann (1821-1870) joined the firm, they established another branch of the business in New York, New York in 1831. Factories were built, first at the corner of Germantown road and Columbia avenue, and later on Fifth street and Cherry street, both in Philadelphia.

The firm was known by a variety of names: William H. Horstmann & Sons (1843-1893, Philadelphia), Horstmann Brothers & Company (1850-1852, New York; 1859-1893, Philadelphia), Horstmann Brothers & Allien (1852-1877, New York), Horstmann Sons & Drucker (1845-1849, New York), and the William H. Horstmann Co. (1893-1940, Philadelphia).